# Trying to sort a hash within an array within a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash-of-hashes

This is what my awkward DB looks like atm. I want to try and sort the nested hashes based on age. I've looked around on SO and all i can find is how to sort hashes inside of hashes, but not when the nested hashes are inside of an array. Im sure there's some easy way to either change the structure or sort it the way it is.

```
{ :room1 => [{
  :fred => { :name => "Fred", :age => 23 },
  :joan => { :name => "Joan", :age => 18 },
  :pete => { :name => "Pete", :age => 54 }
}],
:room2 => [{
  :jan => { :name => "jan", :age => 2 },
  :eric => { :name => "eric", :age => 3 },
  :stan => { :name => "stan", :age => 1 }
}]}
```

Thanks in advance!
Btw, this is my first question on here. Be gentle ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
h.each do |k, v| 
  h[k] = v.first.sort_by { |_, person| person[:age] }.to_h
end
```